# SUMIFs using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am not able to comprehend the concept of SUMIFs in VBA can someone dissect the following code?

```
If WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ActiveSheet.Columns(3), Range("C" & "6").Value, ActiveSheet.Columns(9)) / WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Columns(3), Range("C" & "6").Value) = Range("I" & "6").Value Then
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:-

```
SumIf(ActiveSheet.Columns(3), Range("C" & "6").Value, ActiveSheet.Columns(9))
```

Basically reads like this:-

Add together all the values in Column I (9th column) where the value in Cell C6 appears in the corresponding row in Column C (3rd column).

SUMIF broken down looks like this:-

```
SUMIF(Column containing search values, value to search for, column conaintining items to add)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Yea, I think i understood the first part, Now putting it together i ran the code and saw that if i have duplicate values in 3rd column code goes into the IF construct else it goes out..I mean we can do that using just the countif correct? what is the use of the SUMIF and the "/" in the middle and then the countif.. this is whats confusing me..

Comment: Second part works more or less in the same way - COUNTIF just counts the number of times a value appears in a column.

Comment: What does the "/" signify here?

Comment: Division.  The whole line of code takes the sum of values that match from the SUMIF, divides by the number of items it finds in the COUNTIF, and then checks to see if the answer is equal to whatever value is stored in cell I6.