# Excel VBA Sumif function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a working script that I need to add a sumif to.  I think you should be able to see where I'm trying to enter the formula.  I am trying to reference another sheet in the same workbook.  The section I'm stuck on is if the compPlan = L.

```
Sub CalculateCommission()
    Dim Index As Integer    'Row Index
    Dim employeeName As String 'A
    Dim compPlan As String  'B
    Dim baseWage As Double  'AM
    Dim commAN As Double 'AN
    Dim guarantee As Double 'AO
    Dim earningsDue As Double   'AQ
    Dim priorPay As Double 'AR from prior pay cycle
    Dim priorBase As Integer 'AS from prior pay cycle
    Dim newComm As Double   'AU
    Dim packBack As Double 'AP

    Index = 3

    Do While Len(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Index))
        employeeName = UCase(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Index))
        compPlan = UCase(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Index))
        baseWage = ActiveSheet.Range("AM" & Index)
        newComm = ActiveSheet.Range("AU" & Index)
        earningsDue = ActiveSheet.Range("AQ" & Index)
        guarantee = ActiveSheet.Range("AO" & Index)
        packBack = ActiveSheet.Range("AP" & Index)


        If (IsError(ActiveSheet.Range("AR" & Index)) = False) Then
            priorPay = ActiveSheet.Range("AR" & Index)
        Else
            priorPay = 0
        End If

        If (IsError(ActiveSheet.Range("AS" & Index)) = False) Then
            priorBase = ActiveSheet.Range("AS" & Index)
        Else
            priorBase = 0
        End If

        commAN = ActiveSheet.Range("AN" & Index)


        If compPlan = "B" Or compPlan = "D" Or compPlan = "E" Or compPlan = "I" Or compPlan = "J" Or compPlan = "L" Then
                commAN = earningsDue - baseWage - guarantee - priorBase
            Else
                commAN = earningsDue - baseWage - guarantee
        End If


        If compPlan = "L" Then
                Sumact = Application.SumIf 'Calc by loan'!C:D,"Salesperson",'Calc by loan'!D:D)
        End If



        If compPlan = "B" Or compPlan = "D" Or compPlan = "E" Or compPlan = "I" Or compPlan = "J" Then
            If baseWage + newComm > baseWage Then
                earningsDue = baseWage + newComm + guarantee + priorBase - priorPay + packBack
            Else
                earningsDue = baseWage + guarantee + packBack
            End If
        Else
            If newComm > baseWage + priorPay Then
                earningsDue = newComm - priorPay + guarantee + packBack
            Else
                earningsDue = baseWage + guarantee + packBack
            End If
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Range("AQ" & Index).Value = earningsDue
        Index = Index + 1
    Loop
EndSub:
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the specific problem or error?

Comment: Why is there an `EndSub` line label?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SUMIFs using Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166379/sumifs-using-excel-vba)

Comment: The specific problem is it doesn't calculate the sumif.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I'm not sure.  I didn't write the initial code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use it like this:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Worksheets("Calc by loan").Range("C:C"),"Salesperson",Worksheets("Calc by loan").Range("D:D"))
```

Comment: @JBree You could also use `Application.Evaluate("=SUMIFS('Calc by loan'!C:D,""Salesperson"",'Calc by loan'!D:D)")`

Comment: @DavidZemens I get a runtime error 13 type mismatch with that code.

Comment: `Sumact = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Worksheets("Calc by loan").Range("C:C"),"Salesperson",Worksheets("Calc by loan").Range("D:D"))` does not give me any problems.

Comment: @ScottCraner You're right.  I no longer get the error, but it's not putting the sum in the field.  If I want it in the earningsDue column, should I start it with earningsDue = Application.Worksheet...... ?

Comment: @JBree you do not do anything with Sumact.  so if you want it to show up in a cell then you need to do something with that value.

Comment: @ScottCraner So could I do something like 

earningsDue = Sumact

I'm really new at this (obviously).  Thanks for all your help

Comment: Sure @JBree Just remember that variables only last as long as the procedres are running.  Also please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner I know I'm close.  Here's what I have for that section...

'Lauren comp
        If compPlan = "L" Then
                Sumact = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Worksheets("Calc by loan").Range("C:C"), "Doe, John", Worksheets("Calc by loan").Range("D:D"))
        End If
            ActiveSheet.Range("AQ" & Index).Value = Sumact